# Compare effect of environment between two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
a <- structure(list(Bacteria_A = c(12, 23, 45, 32, 34, 0), Bacteria_B = c(23, 
12, 33, 44, 55, 3), Bacteria_C = c(25, 10, 50, 38, 3, 34), Group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "soil")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample_1", 
"Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5", "Sample_6"))

b <- structure(list(Bacteria_A = c(14, 10, 40, 40, 37, 3), Bacteria_B = c(25, 
14, 32, 23, 45, 35), Bacteria_C = c(12, 34, 45, 22, 7, 23), Group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "water")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample_1", 
"Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", "Sample_5", "Sample_6"))

> a
         Bacteria_A Bacteria_B Bacteria_C Group
Sample_1         12         23         25  soil
Sample_2         23         12         10  soil
Sample_3         45         33         50  soil
Sample_4         32         44         38  soil
Sample_5         34         55          3  soil
Sample_6          0          3         34  soil
> b
         Bacteria_A Bacteria_B Bacteria_C Group
Sample_1         14         25         12 water
Sample_2         10         14         34 water
Sample_3         40         32         45 water
Sample_4         40         23         22 water
Sample_5         37         45          7 water
Sample_6          3         35         23 water
```

I want to compare the difference between each group across samples between soil and water.

For exemple For Bacteria_A i want to know if there is a difference between soil and water. Same for Bacteria_B and Bacteria_c (i have 900 bacteria). I though of a t-test but not sure how to do it with two dataframes.

Forgot to mention that not all bacteria are present in both dataframes so it could happen that one bacteria is not present in one of the environements. If bacteria are found in both environements they have exactly the same name.

Teh original dataframe is 160 samples per 500 Bacteria and data is not normally distributed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `values` do not seem to be in a normal or near-normal distribution, so you should stay away from the t-test. If you are unsure which distribution you are dealing with, you could use a `wilcox.test`.

You can stick your two data frames together quite easily then convert them to long format before running the appropriate tests:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(a,b) %>% 
pivot_longer(c(Bacteria_A, Bacteria_B, Bacteria_C)) %>% 
group_by(name) %>% 
summarise(mean_soil = mean(value[Group == "soil"]), 
          mean_water = mean(value[Group == "water"]), 
          pvalue = wilcox.test(value ~ Group)$p.value)
```

Which gives you

```r
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   name       mean_soil mean_water pvalue
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Bacteria_A      24.3       24    0.936
#> 2 Bacteria_B      28.3       29    0.873
#> 3 Bacteria_C      26.7       23.8  0.748
```

Comment: If this is all the data you have, I agree - a non-parametric test such as the Wilcoxon is more appropriate. However t-tests don't require normality if you have large a sample size

Comment: @alanocallaghan That's true of _paired_ t-tests as long as you can make a reasonable assumption that the _differences_ will be approximately normally distributed. That's usually what you see in Biology, but responses can be all-or-nothing affairs that violate this assumption.  For example, if you measured individual incomes before and after a country changed from a socialist to a capitalist economy, you would likely have heavily skewed residuals that would violate the assumptions of a paired t-test. Without further information on the experiment, a Wilcoxon test is safer.

Comment: It is simply not the case that t-test is valid for non-normal data with large N only for paired tests. The assumption is not of normality of the sample but of normality of the sampling distribution of the sample mean. This is not assured in small samples but per Central Limit Theorem the sampling distribution of the mean asymptotically approaches normal with large N (and fairly quickly). See [this paper](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.23.100901.140546)

Comment: @alanocallaghan I don't disagree with you; if you have _hundreds_ of measurements then the sampling distribution of the mean difference will be normal even if the distribution itself is heavily skewed (e.g. exponential), though often a comparison of means is less useful in that situation.

Comment: Then why comment about paired tests? Why mention skew? The point was "if you have a large sample size".

Comment: @alanocallaghan I guess it was my misinterpretation of what you meant by large. My bad.

Comment: Alright, sorry if I came across as frosty. For the data shown, t-test is definitely inappropriate. I think people (including myself at one point) get fixated on normality as a requirement for linear regression etc, and in many cases you just throw away power when you have a good amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to mention that there are statistical methods to do the comparison which are more adequate than a t-test. They take into account the distribution the numbers are coming from (Negative-Binomial usually). You can check our DESeq2 package for instance.
As to your technical issue I would do:

```
for (bac in setdiff(intersect(colnames(a), colnames(b)), "Group")){
  print(t.test(a[,bac], b[,bac]))
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to say that counts are usually NB-distributed, and I don't think DESeq2 is a great general-purpose recommendation for hypothesis testing for count data.

Comment: That's the first time I hear this opinion, can you refer me to a publication? I'll be happy to read more about it. Regardless, it's certainly not normally distributed.

Comment: Depending on circumstances, there are a lot of probability distributions that might be suitable for counts - binomial, beta-binomial, multinomial, Dirichlet-multinomial, Poisson, negative binomial, zero-inflated negative binomial... The appropriate choice depends on the data generating process and what you want to infer from the data

Answer (score 0):

This finds the bacteria names that exist in both data frames and then does a t.test between the same names giving a list `L` whose names are the bacteria names.  The last line uses `tidy` to convert `L` to a data frame. You can replace `t.test` with `wilcox.test` if you prefer a non-parametric test. (Of course this does not take into account the problems of performing multiple hypothesis tests but rather just does the calculations.)

```
Name <- intersect(names(Filter(is.numeric, a)), names(Filter(is.numeric, b)))
L <- Map(t.test, a[Name], b[Name])

library(broom)
cbind(Name, do.call("rbind", lapply(L, tidy)))
```

The last line gives the following data frame:

```
                 Name   estimate estimate1 estimate2   statistic   p.value
Bacteria_A Bacteria_A  0.3333333  24.33333  24.00000  0.03485781 0.9728799
Bacteria_B Bacteria_B -0.6666667  28.33333  29.00000 -0.07312724 0.9435532
Bacteria_C Bacteria_C  2.8333333  26.66667  23.83333  0.30754940 0.7650662
           parameter  conf.low conf.high                  method alternative
Bacteria_A  9.988603 -20.97689  21.64356 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
Bacteria_B  7.765869 -21.80026  20.46692 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
Bacteria_C  9.492873 -17.84326  23.50993 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

### Note

```
LinesA <- "Bacteria_A Bacteria_B Bacteria_C Group
Sample_1         12         23         25  soil
Sample_2         23         12         10  soil
Sample_3         45         33         50  soil
Sample_4         32         44         38  soil
Sample_5         34         55          3  soil
Sample_6          0          3         34  soil"

LinesB <- "Bacteria_A Bacteria_B Bacteria_C Group
Sample_1         14         25         12 water
Sample_2         10         14         34 water
Sample_3         40         32         45 water
Sample_4         40         23         22 water
Sample_5         37         45          7 water
Sample_6          3         35         23 water"

a <- read.table(text = LinesA, as.is = TRUE)
b <- read.table(text = LinesB, as.is = TRUE)
```